# What is "h" in numerical differentiation?

Tags: math

I would like to know what h from the numerical differentiation formulas is and how I can calculate it when I have a function.

I am speaking about this formulas:

```
f'(x0) = (f(x0 + h) - f(x0)) / h
f'(x0) = (f(x0) - f(x0 - h)) / h
f'(x0) = (f(x0 + h) - f(x0 - h)) / 2*h
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking a math question, not specific to programming.

Comment: where's the programming part of your question?

Comment: ok that clears it up.

Comment: a better question would be to explain that you want it in matlab, not just what the value of it.

Comment: why did you remove the matlab tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such formulae `h` is usually a "very small number", similar to epsilon in Calculus.

For example, the derivative of `f` at `a` is defined as:

[image]

Note how `h` is defined as approaching 0.

---

When programming, e.g. [doing numerical gradient computation](https://github.com/eliben/deep-learning-samples/blob/master/logistic-regression/regression_lib_test.py#L78), it usually works to set `h` to something very small - many programming environments have an "epsilon" quantity; lacking that, you can just use a very small floating-point number.

Comment: Is h always the same number?

Comment: @zer0kai: in a single given equation, yes. But across equations, it's an abstract quantity meaning "very close to 0"

Comment: For example I have the function cos(x) and want to calculate the differentiation at x = 1. Which value should I assign h, when I for example use the formula f'(x0) = (f(x0 + h) - f(x0)) / h?

Comment: @zer0kai: it depends on many things. According to Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation], many TI calculators use h=0.001; in the link I provided above (Python code) I use 1e-5

Answer (score 1):

Using the usual 8 byte floats, sensible values for `h` are `1e-8` for the first and second formula and `1e-5` for the third central difference quotient. This is valid for medium values of `x`, for larger `x` one would have to include the scale of `x` in some way.

In general, for a `k`th order difference quotient with error order `p`, the balance between floating point noise and numerical error is reached for `h` about `pow(2e-16, 1.0/(p+k))`.